# Transformation for zeros

Tags: regression, data-transformation, count-data

I have been working on seed germination experiments with some dormancy breaking treatments and only for some treatments only I got germination. I need to analyze the parameters like days for initial germination and days for final germination. since I got germination for only few treatments and for others no germination and I need to provide analyzed data regarding initial and final days of germination which is not there for some treatments since no seeds germinated in those treatments. so how to analyze these type of data? Is there any transformation needed?

Comment: I don't see how transformation would help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is the question. If you want to model the probability of germination, you have count data, and could start with some poisson model. Search this site.

If you have some other response of interest, which can only be measured in the cases with germination (you didn't tell us), then there will be no information from the seeds which did not germinate, so could be just ignored.  For better suggestions we would need some more context.